# Is it possible to restore a deleted WordPress plugin I deleted from WordPress admin menu?

Tags: plugins, backup

I know it is very, very stupid of me. But I deleted my plugin while I was coding my new plugin. I worked weeks, if not months, on it.
I deleted it from the WordPress admin menu, by just clicking the 'delete' link.

(So stupid, but I was trying if it was possible to delete the plugin and the database table that belongs to the plugin.)

Are there any solutions to get my files back?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The only way would be if your system has running backups. If this is localhost your OS may have a restore option. Otherwise, contact your hosting provider to see what they suggest.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee Hi, thanks for your comment! Yes, I'm running localhost. How can I restore my files? Or isn't that possible anymore?

Comment: It’s not possible unless you’ve been keeping backups of your machine.

Comment: @Mushy I know Windows OS has a Rollback feature but that's out of the scope of this stack.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee I don't think that my system (Windows OS) does have that Rollback feature. But can you explain it anyways?

Comment: If you don't have any backups you are out of luck. What I'd suggest - and, that's off-topic - is using a file recovery tool.